How can I group the common code within two classes that have the exact same definitions but the type of one member variable differs
I have two classes: Motor_Distance and Motor_Displacement that both contain identical code, however the type of the member variable count and the return type of the accessor convToCount is the only difference.
In Motor_Displacement, count is a long since it can be both negative and positive.
In Motor_Distance, count is a unsigned long since it cannot be negative. Thus it is unsigned so i can store higher positive values of count
Here is the code:
constexpr double pi = 3.14159; 

class Motor_Distance{
    private:
        unsigned long count;
        float wheel_diameter;
        unsigned int pulses_per_revolution;
    
    public: 
        unsigned long convToCount(){ return count; }
        
        float convToMeters(){
            return  convToCount() * pi * wheel_diameter / pulses_per_revolution;
        }
};

class Motor_Displacement{
        long count;
        float wheel_diameter;
        unsigned int pulses_per_revolution;
    public:
 
        long convToCount(){ return count; }
  
        float convToMeters(){
            return  convToCount() * pi * wheel_diameter / pulses_per_revolution;
        }
};

int main(){
}

Since both classes contain repeated code, and I want to remove this repeated code. I could achieve this using a template base class as follows:
constexpr double pi = 3.14159; 

template<typename Travel_Type>
class Motor_Travel{
        Travel_Type count;
        float wheel_diameter;
        unsigned int pulses_per_revolution;
    public:
 
        Travel_Type convToCount(){ return count; }
  
        float convToMeters(){
            return  convToCount() * pi * wheel_diameter / pulses_per_revolution;
        }
};

class Motor_Distance : public Motor_Travel<unsigned long>{};
class Motor_Displacement : public Motor_Travel<long>{};

int main(){
}

I there a way I can do a similar thing (group/remove repeated code) without using templates?

seems like an XY problem, why don't you want to use templates ?

You can use the same type instead of 2.

@AhmedAEK I don't want to use templates mainly because every other class in my project doesnt have templates, and I don't want this to be the first (saying this makes me realize this is kind of a dumb reason why not to use templates)

Instead of using inheritance I would have used type-aliases, like using Motor_Distance = Motor_Travel<unsigned long>{};. The reason is that while the two classes two basically do the same calculations, they are still not really siblings in that way. Beyond that, I don't see any nice way of doing something like that without using templates.

As for the reason to not use templates, I personally don't think it's a valid reason. The code will not really use the template except to create the Motor_Distance and Motor_Displacement types (though inheritance or though type aliases).

Ok. Well thanks for your help Some Programmer Dude, Jarod42 and Amed AEK. I will just use templates but use Type-Aliases instead of inheritance

Boost Operators use a CRTP mixin technique to inject functionality into a class.  That same CRTP mixin technique is quite generally useful (but an underutilized language feature, in my opinion).

Another hint for class templates: Each template instantiation duplicates the entire class, so you will also have the similar members and functions duplicated. It may not matter for only two different instantiations, but it can be worth to make a non-template base class with all common members and methods and a templated subtype which handles only the template specific parts. This way only the specific parts get duplicated.
